# Could not create an AWS Lambda function using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am new to CDK, I want to create simple lamda function using CDK.cdk synth gives no error but when I run **cdk deploy --profile myprofile** getting this error

> Resource handler returned message: "User:
> arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-xxxx-ap-south-1/AWSCloudFormation
> is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateFunction on resource:
> arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:xxxxx:function:ApiLamdaStack-helloLamda938CC02A-jS7q9y9UlOUa
> because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:CreateFunction
> action (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID:
> 61895893-bf12-48bf-a51a-dbcf11fc17d8)" (RequestToken:
> 0e3ec851-6bd2-9ef3-751c-a3a947a72668, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)

Here is source code

**bin/api_lamda.ts**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { ApiLamdaStack } from '../lib/api_lamda-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
new ApiLamdaStack(app, 'ApiLamdaStack', {
  env: { account: 'xxx', region: 'yyy' },
});
```

**lib\api_lamda-stack.ts**

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Code, Function as LamdaFunction, Runtime } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Effect, PolicyStatement, CfnPolicy } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';


export class ApiLamdaStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new iam.Role(this, 'example-iam-role', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('cloudformation.amazonaws.com'),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          'AWSLambda_FullAccess',
        ),
      ],
    });

    const helloLamda = new LamdaFunction(this, 'helloLamda', {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, '..', 'services', 'hello')), 
      handler: 'hello.main'
    })

  
  }
}
```

**cdk.json**

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/apiLamda.ts",
  "watch": {
    "include": [
      "**"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "README.md",
      "cdk*.json",
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "**/*.js",
      "tsconfig.json",
      "package*.json",
      "yarn.lock",
      "node_modules",
      "test"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeVersionProps": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021": true,
    "@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs:arnFormatIncludesClusterName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:disableCloudWatchRole": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:enablePartitionLiterals": true,
    "@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions": [
      "aws",
      "aws-cn"
    ]
  }
}
```

All I want to do is create lamda via CDK, can someone please suggest me what to do?

The solution seems to attach role to cloudformation to be able to create lambda function, I have altered the **lib\api_lamda-stack.ts** please take a look

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your cdk code. It says cdk role `cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-xxxx-ap-south-1/AWSCloudFormation` is not authorized to `lambda:CreateFunction`.

Check your profile permissions.

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks, I don't know how to check permissions associated with my profile though from doc ran this command:  aws list-permissions --profile myprofile, but it says command is wong! Also from console, I can see administrator access is attached to the user.

Comment: Your profile assume a role named `cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-xxxx-ap-south-1/AWSCloudFormation` this can be in your account and/or another account. You need to check that role. You may have AdministratorAccess. But cloudformation is using that role while deploying your stack.

Comment: Thanks for setting me in right direction, now I am trying to attach lamda full acess role to cloud formation stack rather doing it from console, I want to do it programatically but still same error, can you please correct what mistake I am making in attaching role?

Comment: Check the docs on bootstrapping, that's how you specify the execution role policies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gshpychka and Mehmet, indeed cdk bootstrap was having issue, I has to completely wipe out rescources created by cdktoolkit stack including s3 and ssm parameter store, they were causing hindrance by not getting removed, so cleaning completely ensured creation complete of bootstrap then deploy succeeded.